# how do I print error when no argv is provided

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please help.

I have a situation where I want to provide an IP address to my script and I want to print an error msg when the address is not provided.

```
    ip = sys.argv[1]


    if len(ip) == 13:
            print "IP address format correct"
    else:
            print "wrong IP format"
            exit()
```

I know I will have to work on the length but that is for later...

Comment: You can take a look around [Try/Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) concept.

Comment: `if len(sys.argv) < 2: raise ValueError("Need an IP address!")`, or use `print` and `sys.exit`

Comment: The last time I counted IP addresses where 7 to 15 characters long and that's just for IPv4 addresses in decimal dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the length of `args` provided is equal to 2 or not. The first argument is always the filename stored at `argv[0]`. So you have to check if length is 2 or more.

Try this :

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Please provide an IP to proceed.")
    sys.exit(0)

ip = sys.argv[1]


if len(ip) == 13:
    print "IP address format correct"
else:
    print "wrong IP format"
    exit()
```

Comment: return
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Ok I thought all this code might be inside a function. `return` cannot be used outside any function. Changed it to `exit()` as you have done incase of wrong `ip` format.

Comment: ip = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I am not sure how that happened. But try to change `exit()` with `sys.exit(0)`.

Comment: Great. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print the given IP to the script
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    print(ip)

    # your condition
    if len(ip) == 13:
        print("IP address format is correct")
    else:
        print("wrong IP format")
        exit()
```

saved as a script `test.py` along with calling the script as:

```
python3 test.py 255.255.255.0
```

or in Python 2.X

```
python test.py 255.255.255.0
```

will do more of less what you want to do for an IP input example as: `255.255.255.0`

Comment: ip = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Run it as ```python3 test.py 255.255.255.0```. The error you give is like if you did not put any input arguments to the script.

Comment: I have to use python 2.7 unfortunately

Comment: Run it as ```python test.py 255.255.255.0``` and it works perfectly with Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Use `argparse` and let it handle this for you.

```
import argparse
import ipaddress


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("address", type=ipaddress.ip_address)

args = p.parse_args()  # Without an argument, parse sys.argv[1:]
```

The `ipaddress` module will take care of validating the IP address. In Python 2.7, you can install `ipaddr` instead and use that, with some slight adjustments. (`ipaddress` is just a slightly modified version of `ipaddr` included in the standard library starting in Python 3.3.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will check if ip is given as input and also validate it.

```
import re
import sys

#check if ip is given
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # regex checking
    s = re.compile('[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')
    # your input
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    if s.match(ip):
        print("{} is valid".format(ip))
    else :
        print("{} is not valid".format(ip))
else:
    print("input ip address")
```